# Is there a generic way to save user layout?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm on a project where we use MVVM pattern.
By user layout: Sorting order of a grid, state of window or control.

For example is it possible to serialize all WPF control layout?

Comment: UserSettings in the .config file.

Comment: @Henk No, I want to save WPF layout without binding each single property.

Answer (score 0):

AvalonDock can serialize its layout, but that won't apply for grid column widths (AvalonDock is by all means great library!).

Also, I have written a set of classes that can make any property (of serializable type) of any object (in an WPF application) persistent only via adding a `[Configurable]` attribute to the property. It shouldn't be hard to customize it to save the properties based on a different criterion than presence of an attribute. But it saves the values on per-type basis, so it might be something else than you are looking for.

I can share if you wish.